# GIT отмена несохраненных изменений в заданном каталоге

Tags: git, git-checkout

Как отменить все несохраненные изменения в рабочем каталоге, чтобы вернуть его к состоянию последнего коммита? Для одного файла делал так:

```
git checkout <file>
```

Как сделать сразу для всех?
Пытался сделать так:

```
git checkout git diff --names-only
git diff --names-only | git checkout
```

Оба способа не работают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так работает?

```
# отменить все изменения в текущем каталоге.
git checkout .

# в любом каталоге относительно текущего
git checkout path/foo/bar

# или то же самое:
cd path/foo/bar
git checkout .

# из любого вложенного каталога — во всем рабочем каталоге
git checkout :/
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо!